# How to control the button delete on react-admin list?

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

How to control the delete button on the react-admin list?
I need to set a confirmation message before deleting a record. Below is the screenshot of the list:

[image]

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60996777/how-to-change-the-delete-confirmation-dialog-title

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `npm i sweetalert2` like :

import Swal from "sweetalert2";
import axios from "axios";

```
onDeleteClick( pk) {

    Swal.fire({
      text :"Are you sure?,
      title: "You won't be able to ,
      type: "question",
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonColor: "#3085d6",
      cancelButtonColor: "#d33",
      confirmButtonText: Yes!,
      cancelButtonText: No!
    }).then(result => {
      if (result.value) {
        axios
          .delete(
            `api ,
            
          )
          .then(res => {
            Swal.fire({
              title: "Deleted",
              type: "success",
              text: " Deleted Successfully !!",
              showConfirmButton: false,
              timer: 2000
            });
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            Swal.fire({
              title: " Deleted",
              type: "error",
              text: "Error While deleting  ??",
              timer: 3000
            });
          
          });
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: but, how i can access this function onDeleteClick ? I have a List and Datagrid component  <List title={"Pesquisa de Acessos"} {...props} actions={(usuario == 0) ?  <NoneActions /> : <Acoes/>} filter={ {UserId : usuario }} >
        <Datagrid>